# ASP.NET hiddenField get value using ClientID as using master pages using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, master-pages

I'm using master pages in .NET and I've discovered that I can't use ID's to retrieve values because .NET adds in it's own id values. See this very helpful article! [Can't get JQuery to work in Master Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841964/cant-get-jquery-to-work-in-master-page)

So I went through and added classes to all the relevant fields, however I ran into a problem when it came to my hidden field `<asp:HiddenField ID="softwareSelected" value="" runat="server" />`

I can't add a class into it, and after more Googling I saw that people fix it by calling `clientID`.

So I tried this:

```
var myHidden = document.getElementById('<%= softwareSelected.ClientID %>');
console.log(myHidden.value);
alert(myHidden.value);
```

Using this answer: [ASP.NET set hiddenfield a value in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454985/asp-net-set-hiddenfield-a-value-in-javascript)

However it isn't returning any value, just an empty alert and console.log.

Could someone point me in the right direction? This is driving me nuts!

EDIT

I set this higher up in my code:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="softwareSelected" ClientIDMode="static" value="test" runat="server" />
```

By putting the ClientIDMode to static I'm getting back `undefined`

Then I try and overwrite this value like this:

```
var myHidden = document.getElementById('<%= softwareSelected.ClientID %>').value;
console.log(myHidden.value);
 myHidden.value = "tester123";
 console.log(myHidden.value);
```

But I still get `undefined` :/

Comment: What is the value are you expecting it to be?

Comment: Just "test" at the moment as the value is hard coded

Comment: When do you set its value to "test"?

Comment: <asp:HiddenField ID="softwareSelected" ClientIDMode="static" value="test" runat="server" />

Comment: You get empty message in alert, because you don't set value in hidden input

Comment: what is  myHidden = "tester123"? Did you mean  myHidden.value = "tester123"?

Comment: @FarzinKanzi oops - yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested that and worked for me. I think your javascript codes are in an external file. If this is you must know that

```
<%= softwareSelected.ClientID %>
```

Only works in you .aspx file.

And if you js scripts are in .aspx file please test this:

```
var myHidden = document.getElementById('JsContent_ softwareSelected').value;
```

If this does not work you must search some where else to you problem.

Comment: My javascript is being called at the bottom of my .aspx page wrapped in a content holder like this: <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="JsContent" runat="server">

Comment: Do you have a master page attached to it?

Comment: Yes of course. Did you debug your code with js debugger? Have you any js code before that you wrote?

Comment: Please one time test this: var myHidden = document.getElementById('JsContent_ softwareSelected').value;

Comment: I was overwriting some JS code - thank you! If you update your answer to say to check for that I'll mark you as correct. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

**ASPX**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="softwareSelected" ClientIDMode="static" value="Hello" runat="server" />
```

**JS**

```
var myHidden = document.getElementById('softwareSelected');
console.log(myHidden.value);
alert(myHidden.value);
```

Comment: I can't do it like that because I'm using .NET master pages, and they add additional values to the ID which means that I can't call them like that. I've gotten round it for every other field by adding in a class, but I can't do that on a hidden field